# Oracle query returning records for a change in sequence of a field value

Tags: oracle, aggregate, analytics, records

Given the following set of records, I'd like to return the first occurrence of 'changed' record.

Given (relevant fields):

```
ID    STATE    REF     DATE
1     state_1  x       2010-12-01
2     state_1  x       2010-12-02
3     state_2  x       2010-12-02
4     state_2  x       2010-12-02
5     state_1  Y       2010-12-03
6     state_3  x       2010-12-03
7     state_4  x       2010-12-03
8     state_2  x       2010-12-03
9     state_1  x       2010-12-03
10    state_1  x       2010-12-04
11    state_2  x       2010-12-04
```

Desired return (for object ref X):

```
ID    STATE    REF     DATE
1     state_1  x       2010-12-01
3     state_2  x       2010-12-02
6     state_3  x       2010-12-03
7     state_4  x       2010-12-03
8     state_2  x       2010-12-03
9     state_1  x       2010-12-03
11    state_2  x       2010-12-04
```

**Further explanation:** 
This is an auditing table that keeps state of objects, and I'd like to track the dates that a change occurred to the state of a certain object.

I'm playing with aggregates/analytic but starting to wonder if they would get me anywhere.

Comment: Rajesh's answer is close, except it also includes ID 8.  But it seems like ID 8 should be in the results.

Comment: You are right - Rajesh's answer seems logic (and awesome). ID 8 is typo on my part - apologies - but Rajesh's query should capture it. I'm adding it to the list of desired results. I will test the answer soon.

Comment: I edited the post to include the results and scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following Query. Basically, you need to get the next value of STATE Columndisplay the current row if if the previous state is different from the current one.

```
create table state_data(
  id number,
  state varchar2(20),
  ref   varchar2(1),
  date1  date);


insert into state_data values (1     ,'state_1','x',to_date('2010-12-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (2     ,'state_1','x',to_date('2010-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (3     ,'state_2','x',to_date('2010-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (4     ,'state_2','x',to_date('2010-12-02','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (5     ,'state_1','Y',to_date('2010-12-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (6     ,'state_3','x',to_date('2010-12-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (7     ,'state_4','x',to_date('2010-12-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (8     ,'state_2','x',to_date('2010-12-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (9     ,'state_1','x',to_date('2010-12-03','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (10    ,'state_1','x',to_date('2010-12-04','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into state_data values (11    ,'state_2','x',to_date('2010-12-04','YYYY-MM-DD'));
commit;
```

-- and then the Query.

```
select id, state, ref, date1 from (
select id, state, ref, date1,
       lag(state) over (order by id asc) prev_state
  from state_data
  )
 where nvl(prev_state,'NULL') != nvl(state,'NULL');


        ID STATE                R DATE1
---------- -------------------- - ---------
         1 state_1              x 01-DEC-10
         3 state_2              x 02-DEC-10
         5 state_1              Y 03-DEC-10
         6 state_3              x 03-DEC-10
         7 state_4              x 03-DEC-10
         8 state_2              x 03-DEC-10
         9 state_1              x 03-DEC-10
        11 state_2              x 04-DEC-10
```

The above result has additional rows than what you showed in the output, 
but looking at your data, it seems like this is the correct result.

Comment: Thank you Rajesh for taking the time to answer and refine this. Your solution worked great. I only had to add the 'X' or 'Y' condition.